# Cannot declare class App\Http\Controllers\CalendarController, because the name is already in use

Tags: php, laravel

So another question, sorry. I'm still new to laravel and I'm implementing a Calendar into an app with lots of content and I'm having an error. I don't know which files are relevant to this error as I don't understand why I'm having it.

This is part of my controller file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Events\Calendar;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Resources\CalendarResource;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class CalendarController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return CalendarResource::collection(Calendar::all());
    }
```

This is my route:

```
Route::get('/', 'Events\CalendarController')->name('events');
```

This is my error:

```
Cannot declare class App\Http\Controllers\CalendarController, because the name is already in use
```

And when I do `php artisan route:list` I get this:

```
ReflectionException  : Class App\Http\Controllers\Events\CalendarController does not exist
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error when after doing a full search of every file, the name "CalendarController" is only used once.

Thanks.

Comment: `'Events\CalendarController'` fails because your namespace is `App\Http\Controllers`.If you have a CalendarController in `App\Http\Controllers` and `App\Http\Controllers\Events`, then you need to fix the namespace on the one in Events.

Comment: I changed the namespace to `App\Http\Controllers\Events;` now I'm getting the error: `Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Events\Controller' not found`

Comment: You'll have to add the full namespace for `extends Controller`

Comment: How do you mean? Can I have an example, sorry I'm new to this.

Comment: do you have `CalendarController` in `App\Http\Controllers\Events;` folder

Comment: Yes. It's Events/CalendarController.php

Comment: add `use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;` in your code , also check if your `CalendarController`  class name and file name i.e `CalendarController.php` is same or not .

Comment: That fixed it, but now I have SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table '(redacted)' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `calendars`). I'm trying to find where I've changed a keyword now

Comment: Creating multiple file with same name may result to this situation. try 'composer dump-autoload' in your command